# how to switch between two DatePickers in onDateSet()?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a DialogFragment that is set up to handle two different DatePickers.  The "FilterNum" in the bundle allows me to use two different setTitle() for the two DatePickers.

The DialogFragment uses a listener to return the selected date to the OnDateSet() in the MainActivity.  I would like to be able to set up a switch method in OnDateSet so that if DatePicker #1 is selected then case #1 code is executed or if DatePicker #2 is selected then case #2 code is executed.

```
MainActivity

...
DatePicker #1

beforeDueDateLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("FilterNum",1);
            FilterDueDatesFragment filterFragment = new FilterDueDatesFragment();
            filterFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            filterFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "filterDatePicker");                
            dialogFilter.dismiss();
        }
    });

DatePicker #2

afterDueDateLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("FilterNum",2);
            FilterDueDatesFragment filterFragment = new FilterDueDatesFragment();
            filterFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            filfilterFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "filterDatePicker");
            dialogFilter.dismiss();

FilterFragment extends DialogFragment
...  
static final int ON_OR_BEFOREFILTER = 1;
static final int ON_OR_AFTERFILTER= 2;
private int mChosenFilter;
int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        mChosenFilter = bundle.getInt("FilterNum");
    }

    if (getActivity() != null) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity();

    DatePickerDialog pickerBefore;
    DatePickerDialog pickerAfter;       

    switch (mChosenFilter) {

        case ON_OR_BEFOREFILTER:
            pickerBefore = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, listener, year, month, day);
            pickerBefore.setTitle("Select 'On or Before' due date");
            return pickerBefore;

        case ON_OR_AFTERFILTER:
            pickerAfter = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, listener, year, month, day);
            pickerAfter.setTitle("Select 'On or After' due date");
            return pickerAfter;
        }
    return null;
    }

MainActivity OnDateSet()

    @Override
    public void   
        onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            // this is where i need to set up different code 
            if (pickerBefore) {
                ...
            }
            if (pickerAfter) {
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove from your MainActivity your onDateSetListener, and instead add 2 methods onDateSetPicker1(int year, int month, int day) and onDateSetPicker2(int year, int month, int day). And then in your dialog fragment use this code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        mChosenFilter = bundle.getInt("FilterNum");
    }

    if (getActivity() != null) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onDateSetPicker1(int year, int month, int day);
        }
    }
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onDateSetPicker2(int year, int month, int day);
        }
    }

    DatePickerDialog pickerBefore;
    DatePickerDialog pickerAfter;       

    switch (mChosenFilter) {

        case ON_OR_BEFOREFILTER:
            pickerBefore = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, listener1, year, month, day);
            pickerBefore.setTitle("Select 'On or Before' due date");
            return pickerBefore;

        case ON_OR_AFTERFILTER:
            pickerAfter = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, listener2, year, month, day);
            pickerAfter.setTitle("Select 'On or After' due date");
            return pickerAfter;
        }
    return null;
    }
```

So you will have different listeners in your dialog, and these different listeners will call different methods of your parent activity.

Comment: Looks good, I will give it a try.  Basically set up two custom methods in the MainActivity that call OnDateSet within them.

Comment: No luck so far.  Android Studio doesn't like this line:  ((MainActivity)getActivity).onDateSetPicker1(int year, int month, int day);  Error message is "cannot resolve symbol 'getActivity'.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Ok, minor edit fixed it:  getActivity becomes getActivity() and second onDateSetPicker1 becomes onDateSetPicker2.  Answer upvoted and accepted.  Cheers!